# ruby on rails in RPI

Tags: gpio, ruby

I want to control my RPI from my phone, so I decided that the RPI will host a site. I'm familiar with ROR and I saw that there is GPIO gem (pi piper).

Should I work with ROR or learn Django and use python's stable module instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can use that gem as far as it will do whatever you want to do; it is obviously unmaintained now and doesn't include, e.g., I2C support.<sup>1</sup> However, I notice there may be some other generic ruby modules for I2C on linux (they *do not* have to be specifically for the pi).

Much of the GPIO functionality can be controlled via the `/sys/class/gpio` interface, which does not require any module; you are just reading from and writing to file nodes the kernel presents to userland.  Basic documentation for that [is here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt); you may find further explanations online but it is really very simple.

Note that that interface does not allow you to do certain things, such as activate internal pull-up/down resistors (but I think the `pi_piper` module does).  You have not said what it is you are actually trying to do, so you may or may not require that.

---

<sup>1. It also may not work, or work completely, on the A+/B+ or pi 2.</sup>

Comment: I want something to control my garden from my phone. So I need also ORM for saving some data

Answer (score 2):

From your comments above, the gem sounds unmaintained, while [RPi.gpio looks to be active](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/).

Depending on the complexity of your web application, you may be able to get up and running much faster with a [microframework like flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).